# How to retrieve a subset of embedded documents in MongoDB?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have a User document, which has an array of embedded log event documents, of which have dates and times as well as other info. Is there any way I can retrieve the User document and ONLY a subset of the embedded log events, based on date?

Comment: I'm thinking this is currently not possible. There's lots of discussion about virtual collections for this kind of thing, all of which were around 8-12 months ago, but it doesn't appear to have been implemented yet.

Comment: Maybe something like `db.users.find({ 'user.logs' : {created_on: {$gte: start, $lt: end}})` from [Querying for a Date Range (Specific Month or Day)](http://cookbook.mongodb.org/patterns/date_range/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**It's not possible at the moment.**

As of 1.5.1, you can use [the `$slice` operator](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Retrieving+a+Subset+of+Fields) to do something similar, but only if your log objects are already ordered by date (which theoretically should be the case because you generally don't log something in the past):

```
> db.User.findOne({}, {"logs":{$slice: -2}}) // last two
> db.User.findOne({}, {"logs":{$slice: 2}}) // first two
```

Unfortunately, this will not allow you to precisely search in the middle of the subset by date.

Comment: I figured as much. I'd looked into the slice operator, but it's not quite what I'm after. Basically the idea is that users can view their usage for specific time intervals. Thanks anyway! Also, I'm marking this as the answer because now I know it's still not possible.